# Java FakeSMTP can't recieve my message because of timeout

Tags: java, smtpclient

I got an assigment to make a simple SMTP Email sender client without using any pre-implemented external library. The server which have to recieve my messages is the FakeSMTP (http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/) which runs on localhost. 
When I try to send a message I get the following error:

```
220 DESKTOP-T6LJE71 ESMTP SubEthaSMTP null
421 Timeout waiting for data from client.
Error while sending email
java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

My code is:

```
public class SMTP {
    public static void sendHeader(DataOutputStream msgToSend, BufferedReader responseFromServer) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        msgToSend.writeBytes("HELO\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        msgToSend.writeBytes("MAIL FROM:<something@gmail.com>\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        msgToSend.writeBytes("RCPT TO:<anything@gmail.com>\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        msgToSend.writeBytes("DATA\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
    }

    public static void sendContent(DataOutputStream msgToSend, BufferedReader responseFromServer) throws IOException {
        msgToSend.writeBytes("From:<something@gmail.com>\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes("To:<anything@gmail.com>\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes("Subject:Test\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes("Hello world.\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes("Hello world.\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes("Hello world.\n");
        msgToSend.writeBytes(".\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        msgToSend.writeBytes("QUIT\n");
        System.out.println(responseFromServer.readLine());
        System.out.println("Closing connection");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        try{
            Socket serverSocket=new Socket("localhost",25);
            BufferedReader responseFromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream messageToServer = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
            sendHeader(messageToServer,responseFromServer);
            sendContent(messageToServer, responseFromServer);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while sending email");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find out where is the problem. Any help is appreciated, thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: what's the port SMTP uses?

Comment: Why?  If you want to be able to talk to every smtp server, the job is bigger than you think.  Gmail is particularly picky.

Comment: The port is 25. It's a simple university assignment to get the basics of the SMTP, we don't have to make it work in real life, the gmail emails I wrote are just two random examples to see if I get the messages.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP commands are supposed to be terminated by `<CRLF>` but you are sending only `<LF>`. Some SMTP servers are really picky about that, but I can't be sure about yours.

So try using `\r\n` instead of `\n` in your messages.

```
msgToSend.writeBytes("HELO\r\n");
```

If that doesn't fix it, another possible problem is that the outgoing messages may be accumulating in the write buffer. Calling `flush()` may help.

```
msgToSend.flush();
```